# Options for licensing DNN Modules?

Tags: licensing, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

We're looking to sell our DNN modules, but we want to make sure each module is restricted to ONE DNN install (if user wants to install a module multiple times, multiple modules must be purchased).

What DNN licensing solutions can you recommend? I'm not looking for the cheapest option, but for the best.

Budget is $400.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open source system on Codeplex you could integrate with.

[Install Key - on codeplex](http://installkey.codeplex.com/)

Set that up, and then you would have to custom write a control you could use as the 'edit' module definition in DNN and that could have your logic for licensing your component.

But yeah this generates a key, then when you auth it hits a web service to validate it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the way used by Mandeeps.com , when you install a module it will ask you for an activation key and the validation will be done throw a web service they have developed ,, in this way you can customize your business logic as you want with just this web service and the customers table in your database

Answer (score 0):

[Licence Master](http://www.dotcomsoftwaresolutions.com/en/Products/Licence-Master.aspx) is a complete licensing solution for DNN module developers. You install it in your DNN site just like any other module. You integrade your own modules with Licence Master using a Client API library. This library enables your module to communicate with your licence server and to manage and validate licence keys.

Licence Master manages all aspects of the licensing process including issue, registration, upgrades, renewals and automated notifications.